# wxmaxima 0.8.4: defining a vector without defining its component

Tags: vector, maxima, dot-product

Let's have the following code

```
e1 : matrix([a1],[b1],[c1]);
e2 : matrix([a2],[b2],[c2]);
dotproduct(e1,e2);
```

the 3rd line gives the output

```
a1a2 + b1b2 +c1c2
```

I would like to have something like this instead (`|e|` is the norm of `e`):

```
|e1||e2|
```

Is there a way for [wxMaxima](https://github.com/andrejv/wxmaxima/releases/tag/Version-0.8.4) to give a simplified answer for the dotproduct function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution, although this isn't entirely satisfactory.

Instead of calling `dotproduct`, just write dot products as `a . b`. (The `.` operator means noncommutative multiplication in Maxima.) You can define a simplification rule so that `a . b` simplifies to an expression involving `a` and `b` and the angle between them.

```
matchdeclare ([aa, bb], nonscalarp);
tellsimpafter (aa . bb, norm(aa)*norm(bb)*cos(angle(aa, bb)));
```

With this, I get:

```
(%i12) declare ([e1, e2], nonscalar);
(%o12) done
(%i13) e1.e2;
(%o13) norm(e1)*cos(angle(e1,e2))*norm(e2)
```

Maybe this much is helpful, you can say whether it is. It isn't so great because you'll have to define `norm` yourself and also `angle(a, b)`. This is a weakness in Maxima -- its coverage of this stuff is hit or miss.

Or maybe you don't need `norm` and `angle` to be defined -- I suppose it depends on your purposes. Maybe you can say more about what is the larger problem you're trying to solve.

Also, this solution is a little problematic because only a two-term product `a . b` will match. With three terms, `a . b . c`, the pattern matcher thinks it doesn't fit. There are various ways around that, again, none of them entirely satisfactory.

All the same, I hope this is useful to you in some way.

Comment: I don't need both norm and angle to be defined, moreover i only have two-term product, so your answer greatly fit my needs. Just one question: does this solution cover distribution: if i write (a+b).c, will maxima gives a.c + b.c ?

Comment: Simplification of `(a + b).c` is governed by the global flag `dotdistrib`. The default value is `false`. When `dotdistrib` is `true`, `(a + b).c` simplifies to `a.c + b.c`. Since the rule above was defined by `tellsimpafter`, it is applied after any built-in simplifications. So you'll get the rule applied to `a + b` and `c`, or to `a` and `c` and `b` and `c`, depending on the value of `dotdistrib`.